# Address of specific instance in Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have 2 EC2 instances configured in an Amazon ELB.  I have a custom domain name associated with this ELB.  Each EC2 instance has IIS website configured with this host name.  I would like to somehow directly access the website on a specific instance in the ELB via the browser.  Is it possible to get the public "host name" of each individual instance in the ELB ?  Thanks.

EDIT: I am able to get the individual public IPs of each instance but cannot use them in the URL to the website for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have met below conditions:

1. The Instances are in EC2-classic. OR in other words, the instances are NOT in a private Subnet of VPC
2. The instance do have a public IP address/Hostname assigned.
3. You do have right security group assigned to the instance which will allow port 80 and 443 access from the internet (0.0.0.0/0)

If above 3 conditions are met, then I do not see a reason why would you not be able to access these instances via URL.

BTW, it does not make seine to access the instances directly via URL while they are behind a Load balancer. Anyway, that's a different conversation altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  All 3 conditions are met.  For item 2, there is only a public IP address.  I think I may have solved the access by configuring a localhost website on each instance that points to the same application.  Now I am able to use that public IP address to get to the page.  FYI, I needed to get to the specific instance for debugging purposes only just in case something goes wrong on only 1 of the instances.